# How to include html tags inside the text method of an `options_from_collection_for_select`?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a form that has a select_tag, and I want to format the displayed text a certain way. Here's what I tried so far, in the object's model:

```
def display_name
    return description.upcase+"<div class='pull-right'>"+date.upcase+"</div>"
end
```

This doesn't work, I just end up with html as a string.

I already tried adding `.html_safe`:

```
return descricao.upcase+"<div class='pull-right'>".html_safe+date.upcase+"</div>".html_safe
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It should be like: `return "#{descricao.upcase}<div class='pull-right'>#{date.upcase}</div>".html_safe`

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to nest a `div` inside of an `option` element? That would be invalid html, because the `option` element only allows [text content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element).

Comment: You're both right, the string @Abhi described did seem to get parsed, but like @spickermann said, no divs were created inside the option tag, leaving only `descricao.upcase - date.upcase`. I guess there is no way to align `date.upcase` to the right then. Thanks though